# Insert values into MySQL table if value does not already exist?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I wish to insert nested lists into mysql table using Python. I want to insert new rows for new ID values and update certain columns for those with existing ID values. However, for one of these nested lists (Fruits, s[2]) I only want to update these rows within mysql Table if those records are empty! I realise the query I have put only works for new inserting id numbers and does not address updating existing rows. That's where I need help!

```
s = [[1, 20, 21],[1999, 1998, 1990], ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Bannana']

id = s[0] 
yearborn = s[1] 
favfruit = s[2]

query = '''INSERT INTO table (PersonID, Year, Fruit) 
           VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'''

cursor.executemany(query, s)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to insert new rows for new ID values and update certain columns for those with existing ID values.

In MySQL, you can use the [`insert ... on duplicate key` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), and some conditional logic to only `update` column `fruit` if it is initially `null`:

```
insert into table (personid, year, fruit) 
values (%s, %s, %s)
on duplicate key update 
    year = values(year), 
   fruit = coalesce(fruit, values(fruit));
```

For this to work, you need a unique (or primary key) constraint on column `personid`.

Comment: I have this but for some reason "fruit = coalesce...." does not seem to have any effect?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not have any effect*?

Comment: So the first line "values (year) works fine. But the coalesce() does not appear to change the values. Is this perhaps because no null value has been set within the mysql table. It's definately a blank entry but appears like this --> ' '? I'm not sure if I'm just guessing here though? coalesce assumes null entries?

Comment: @Sam: `coalesce()` operates on `null` values. If your values are empty strings, then: `fruit = case when fruit = '' then values(fruit) else fruit end`. Or you can handle both: `fruit = case when fruit = '' or fruit is null then values(fruit) else fruit end`